# add days to date in sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a date field `Date of join` and other field `Date on induction` (date type). Based on some selection I want to calculate If `Date of join` is 20/05/2015 then `Date on induction` should be auto selected as `Date of join` + 7 days, like result should be 27/05/2015.

Can you please let me know how I can acheive with SharePoint Designer Workflow

Comment: So, you just want to check a date, and if true add days? Will it only be 20/05/2015? No other dates?

Comment: I am trying to do the same except that "7" is not constant.
I want to add dates based on lookup from a different column. For example - Column A (StartDate) + Column B (Days in numbers) = Column C (DueDate) Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are looking for a SharePoint designer workflow solution, then I believe there is a 2 step solution to it.

**1.** Based on the submitted value of `Date of join` field calculate resulting induction date. This can be achieved by using `Add Time to Date` action.

Set the values to match your requirement in action, like add `7` change `minutes to Days` and lastly to `CurrentItem:Date Of Join`. Refer below screen shot.

[image]

**2.** Now once you get the result date in a variable from the previous step, We just need to set it to the `Date of join` field using `Set Field in current item` action. Refer below screen shot

[image]

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest option is to add a Calculated Field to your list and use below formula.

```
=[Date of join]+7
```

And then read this value in your workflow

If you are against Calculated Field. Then in Workflow you can use Action `Add Time To Date`

1. Create a new Variable to Store the result
2. Now insert and Action and set `Add 7 Days to CurrentItem:Date of join` output to Variable
3. Use `Update List Item` action to update variable value into `Date of induction` field.